# Magento dynamic attribute/option save to cart

Tags: php, magento

I need to dynamically add option choices to the cart items at the time a product is added to the cart. The choices presented to the shopper can change from product to product, so it is necessary that they are dynamic. However, the options will always be the same. For example "Option 1" might have values "a, b, c" for one product and "x, y, z" for another product. I do not need the options saved into the product, only the cart. The selections need to be displayed in the cart and in the order administration, receipt, etc.

I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793486/add-option-value-to-product-then-to-cart-with-magento) that I can use `$cart->addProduct($product, $params)` in order to set custom options to the cart item.

I found that I can override the Cart controller at [this blog post](http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.com/2010/11/magento-overwrite-cart-controller-add.html). I was able to dynamically add the product to the cart. However, I am stuck on how to add dynamic attribute values to the product. I tried setting 'options' and 'super_attribute' in `$params` before calling `$cart->addProduct($product, $params)` but it's not saving the values to the cart item.

Finally, some of the option choices would need to affect the product price. I am not sure how to account for this either.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I have use a combination of text field and drop-down option (for options which affect price) along with custom javascript and hidden field to solve this issue. Take a look at the example below, as you change the different cabinet width the total dimension and price will be  updated. This information will also be add to cart/admin order

see example @ http://www.contempospace.com/bedroom-furniture/wardrobe-closets/custom-closet-systems/isa-custom-closet-4-module/isa-closet-system-xl-maximize-large-closet-drawers-shelves-hanging.html

Assuming that you are using simple product.

**To add additional_options** see [Magento - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266)

**To change product price** see [Changing the price in quote while adding product to cart: magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento)

Comment: It's a nice website. I am able to create a new <select> field with php/html and put dynamic options into it. However I don't know how to supply the selected option and the price variation to Magento when I add the product to the cart using $cart->addProduct(). Did you solve the same problem, if so do you have some insight or code you can share?

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266 (for adding product options)... http://bit.ly/dby1mw (for changing price)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this! I tried the solution in the first link for adding product options. It works very well. However in the second link for changing prices, they mention at the top of the page that it doesn't work in versions 1.6.2 or later. Do you know of another solution for this?

Comment: Take a look at these  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798069/creating-a-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento-automatically/2798457#2798457 . Please let me know which one work.

Comment: The first link was exactly what I needed. Thanks so much for the help R.S!